# Como alterar uma tabela para inserir um campo de chave estrangeira?

Tags: mariadb, dbeaver

Olá, estou tentando setar um campo *user_status* em uma tabela já existente de nome **cl_users** usando **MariaDB** no DBeaver, a tabela em questão irá referenciar uma outra tabela também já existente com 4 campos de status que tem os valores já cadastrados que são:

```sql
|             cl_users_status            |    
ID int NOT NULL Primary Key | varchar(15)
               0              sysmanager
               1              admin
               2              employee
               3              customer
```

eu estou usando o comando

```sql
ALTER TABLE cl_users 
ADD CONSTRAINT user_status
FOREIGN KEY (id) 
REFERENCES cl_users_status(id);
```

Quando eu executo o comando acima o DBeaver retorna o seguinte erro:

```
SQL Error [1005] [HY000]: 
Can't create table `clinica`.`#sql-275c_16` (
errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"
)
Can't create table `clinica`.`#sql-275c_16` (
errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"
)
Can't create table `clinica`.`#sql-275c_16` (
errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"
)
```

Certamente é um erro na sintaxe, só que não sei exatamente o que está errado, gostaria de receber uma ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de tentar com vários comandos eu mesmo consegui resolver o problema da seguinte maneira:

```sql
ALTER TABLE clinica.cl_users
ADD user_status INT;

ALTER TABLE clinica.cl_users 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_user_status FOREIGN KEY (user_status) not null
REFERENCES cl_users_status(id);

UPDATE clinica.cl_users
SET user_status=0
WHERE ID=0;
```

Se alguém souber como resolver isso com um único comando deixa aí para ajudar quem estiver tentando resolver o mesmo problema.

O que faltava era ter o campo **user_status** na tabela antes de setar ele como uma Foreign Key pois somente com o comando:

```sql
ALTER TABLE clinica.cl_users 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_user_status FOREIGN KEY (user_status) not null
REFERENCES cl_users_status(id);
```

O mesmo retornava um erro.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
ALTER TABLE cl_users
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_user_status
FOREIGN KEY (user_status)
REFERENCES cl_users_status(id);
```

Comment: Não funcionou:
O erro foi

```sql
SQL Error [1072] [42000]: Key column 'user_status' doesn't exist in table
  Key column 'user_status' doesn't exist in table
  Key column 'user_status' doesn't exist in table

```